# How to elegantly recode multiple columns containing multiple values

Tags: r, tidyverse, plyr

I have a dataframe with a mix of continuous and categorical data.

```
df<- data.frame(gender=c("male","female","transgender"),
                    education=c("high-school","grad-school","home-school"),
                    smoke=c("yes","no","prefer not tell"))
> print(df)
       gender   education           smoke
1        male high-school             yes
2      female grad-school              no
3 transgender home-school prefer not tell
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ gender   : chr  "male" "female" "transgender"
 $ education: chr  "high-school" "grad-school" "home-school"
 $ smoke    : chr  "yes" "no" "prefer not tell"
```

I'm trying to recode the categorical columns to nominal format. My current approach is significantly tedious.
First, I have to convert all character variables to factor format,

```
# Coerce all character formats to Factors
df<- data.frame(df[sapply(df, is.character)] <-
  lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], as.factor))

library(plyr)
df$gender<- revalue(df$gender,c("male"="1","female"="2","transgender"="3"))
df$education<- revalue(df$education,c("high-school"="1","grad-school"="2","home-school"="3"))
df$smoke<- revalue(df$smoke,c("yes"="1","no"="2","prefer not tell"="3"))
> print(df)
  gender education smoke
1      1         1     1
2      2         2     2
3      3         3     3
```

Is there a more elegant way to approach this problem? Something along the lines of `tidyverse` style will be helpful. I have already seen somewhat similar questions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311446/is-there-a-way-to-recode-multiple-variables-at-once), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602107/using-mutate-over-multiples-columns-with-a-for-loop-to-recode-values),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618150/how-to-recode-multiple-columns-in-r). The issue with these solutions are either they are not relevant to what I seek or else they using base R approaches like `lapply()` or `sapply()`, which is difficult for me to interpret. I would also like to know if there is an elegant approach to convert all character variables to factor format along the lines of tidyverse approach.

Comment: Maybe try `df %>% mutate(across(gender:smoke,~as.numeric(.)))` if variables are factors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just take into account that we are using `mutate()` and `across()` twice in order to first transform values to factor ordered by how they appear in each variable (`unique()`), and then the numeric side with `as.numeric()` to extract the values. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% mutate(across(gender:smoke,~factor(.,levels = unique(.)))) %>%
  mutate(across(gender:smoke,~as.numeric(.)))
```

Output:

```
  gender education smoke
1      1         1     1
2      2         2     2
3      3         3     3
```

And in order to identify how the new values will be assigned you can use this:

```
#Code 2
df %>% summarise_all(.funs = unique) %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% mutate(Newval=1:n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name      value           Newval
  <chr>     <fct>            <int>
1 education high-school          1
2 education grad-school          2
3 education home-school          3
4 gender    male                 1
5 gender    female               2
6 gender    transgender          3
7 smoke     yes                  1
8 smoke     no                   2
9 smoke     prefer not tell      3
```

Or maybe for more control:

```
#Code 3
df %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  left_join(df %>% summarise_all(.funs = unique) %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
              arrange(name) %>%
              group_by(name) %>% mutate(Newval=1:n()) %>% ungroup()) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Newval) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  gender education smoke
   <int>     <int> <int>
1      1         1     1
2      2         2     2
3      3         3     3
```

In case your variables are of class `character` you can use this pipeline to transform from character to factor, then re organize the factor and then make them numeric:

```
#Code 4
df %>% 
  mutate(across(gender:smoke,~as.factor(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(gender:smoke,~factor(.,levels = unique(.)))) %>%
  mutate(across(gender:smoke,~as.numeric(.)))
```

Output:

```
  gender education smoke
1      1         1     1
2      2         2     2
3      3         3     3
```

Comment: really appreciate for the quick response including alternative possible solutios, but are you sure it works? I have checked the proposed solution multiple times including restarting RStudio, and I'm not able to reproduce the solution. It still prints the data in categorical format and not nominal.

Comment: @mnm Hi, I have tested with your `df`. Maybe check the `str()` of `df`, are they factors or characters? I have your `df` as factor variables. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: @mnm Also check I saw you load `plyr`. Maybe is producing issues with `dplyr`. Try first loading `plyr` and after that `dplyr` or the `tidyverse`

Comment: it seems to work now. The problem was the variables were of character data type. I have revised the Q to include a tedious approach for converting character to factor. Is there another way to it along the lines of tidyverse style?

Comment: @mnm I have added an option, you basically can use `across()` with `as.factor()` and the continue with the pipeline included at the start of the post. I hope that can be helpful!

Comment: many thanks for the solution.  It works now. I'm accepting your proposed solution because you've not only answered the Q but also suggested possible solutions to further question extensions..

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the character and factor column in your data to numeric giving each level a unique value based on their occurrence in the data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~is.character(.) | is.factor(.)), ~match(., unique(.))))

#  gender education smoke
#1      1         1     1
#2      2         2     2
#3      3         3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
lapply(df, function(x){
    if(is.character(x) | is.factor(x)){
      x <- as.integer(labels(as.factor(x)))
    }else{
      x
    }
  }
)
```